# Hibernate returns only one result (After changing table names)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I am using hibernate retrieve results from my MySQL database into my Java project. Recently, I had a lot of redundant data and had to manually clean up the database by copying the required data into new tables and then renaming the newly created table to old table.

But, now querying the database with hibernate gives only one row as the result. I have manually checked the database and there are several different rows in the database. My query to Hibernate is something like this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(UserDto.class);
c.setMaxResults(100);
List<UserDto> users = c.list();
```

`users` contains 100 elements but all are the same.

The mapping of userDto is [here](https://github.com/pulkit110/Twitter-Data-Miner/blob/master/src/main/java/twitter/dto/UserDto.java).

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Can you add the hibernate mapping for UserDTO class and the schema of the corresponding table in db.  The most likely reason for this is that you have mapped the wrong column as id

Comment: Please tell us what is your mapping, what is your db data, andt the sql queries that are fired (hibernate.show.sql=true) and your equals method in the entity (don't think it matters since a list is returned but...)

Comment: @gkamal I have updated the question accordingly!

Comment: Can you post the SQL query hibernate is firing in this case.  As @Nikem answer suggests an join to a ToMany can also lead to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your UserDto class has ToMany relations, then this is quite possible that outer join on them results in many records which all contain one and the same user data. You should use

```
session.createCriteria(UserDto.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. However, I am can get all the data using  `Session.createQuery`. I am  not sure why criteria doesn't work though.

Comment: @Nikem: That might be true if the ManyToMany relationships are eagerly fetched, but I don't see that in the mapping.  IIRC the default is FetchMOde.LAZY.   In any case, Hibernate won't fetch more than one X-to-many at a time, *and* it does know how to deal with the redundant rows in most cases (depends on the query).

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your mapping of the UserDto class to the database. 
My guess is that you don't have it mapped to the table that you think you do.
As Sebastien mentioned, setting hibernate.show.sql to true should make this obvious.

Comment: The mapping is correct. Using `Session.createQuery` returns the correct results as well. I am just not sure why criteria doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you deleted the old tables? And in the configuration file what is the value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"?

Comment: I didn't delete them but did rename them to something else which doesn't interfere with the mappings. The value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is `validate`.

Comment: One thing you can try. Delete the newly created tables and let the hibernate create the table for you by using the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value as "create". Once the tables are created then you can insert programatically through insert statements.

Comment: @Chandu I'm not sure why that would help.   If the tables were renamed and copied then the schema should be the same.  In my projects 'hbm2ddl.auto=create' is only allowed for testing.   You really don't want Hibernate creating the schema for a production database, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is these records have same id, so Hibernate treat them as the same record. You can check it.

Comment: How would that happen?  No primary keys defined maybe?  Hibernate can appear to behave strangely if you don't define primary keys.  If that's the problem then.... maybe it's time to step away from the keyboard.

Comment: The primary keys are defined. See the mapping

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my case, the problem detected when I created a table in MySQL manually and I tried to read data from that table using hibernate and a dto class. After checking my dto class fields and database table, I figured out that there is a difference between table column named "id" and the class field which named dbId. The code was something like this:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue 
@Column(name="db_id", unique = true)
private long dbId;
```

So I edited the name and changed the code:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue 
@Column(name="id", unique = true)
private long dbId;
```

Which "id" was the correct name of databse table column and the problem has been solved.